# The remote name could not be resolved: '*****.sharepoint.com' in O365 Online Sharepoint in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, dns, web-config, http-proxy

I am uploading files from a specific drive in the host computer to a Sharepoint Site, for this I have used Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll & Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll. Most of the times my script works fine, but at times I get the error:

- "Failed to connect to SharePoint Online site: 'https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX'"
- "Exception Type: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException"
- "Exception Message: Exception calling ""ExecuteQuery"" with ""0"" argument(s): ""The remote name could not be resolved: 'XXX.sharepoint.com'"""

Any ideas of what might be causing the error and how I could prevent the script from crashing again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As most of the times, the script works.

I assuming that it could be some network issue in your side.

Did you use some proxy in you side and can you access the site url in browser directly ?

I suggest you can trace the request using Fiddler to see if there is some detailed error message when executing the script:

[Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: No, we are not using any proxy and yes we can access the site url using the browser directly. I wll try Fiddler and see if something comes up. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: You can trace the web request and share the update if possible. We will continue try to help you with the detailed information.

Comment: Thank you! Once I figure I gather more information I will update.